# Problems with ffmpeg build in Xcode

Tags: xcode, ffmpeg

Hi I have a problem with getting ffmpeg libraries to build in my Xcode project. It is in C++ . I have installed it using homebrew and have checked that all the correct libraries have installed via terminal. I have tried with and without extern C as I know it is a c library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <libavformat>

//extern "C" {
//    #include <libavformat>
//}
```

The linker flags have been set by using (e.g. pkg-config --libs libavcodec) in terminal and these flags do not throw up an error when building. The header files are also found with no problems as the autocomplete flags them top while typing.

Please see attached pictures for Xcode build settings. Really stuck pease help[image: Xcode build settings]

[image: Xcode build settings 2]

Comment: forgot to mention the error code is as follows "libavformat file not found"

Answer (score 0):

I identified the problem as being related to the path that the include statement relates to. The header files were one down in the hierarchy from the folders so:

```
#include <libavformat>
```

produces an error that the library was not found. The change below sorted the problem out.

```
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
```